# asp.net advanced search form, results in a grid and back button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a asp.net forms web application where I've got advanced search form with grid listing results below. Grid is sortable and pageable. Grid is listing products.

I've got two requirements :

1) make the url remember the advanced search form state so search results page can be bookmarked etc.

2) on the product details page there is a back button that should take the user to the advanced search page with the same settings in the form and same grid state.

I have implemented a workaround to above two problems but I don't think my solution is very clean and I'd like to hear better ideas. My workaround is as follows :

1) I iterate through form fields and I put values into the querystring after the hash. So when the page is loaded it gets the values from url if available.

2) when user clicks a link to product details page from the grid I use javascript to create a cookie with url to advanced search page so when rendering the product details page I know the url for the back button.

I'd like to achieve above functionality in cleaner way.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the search page form action to GET. This will put everthing in the query string for you, enabling the bookmarking and the back button.

Comment: That's right, I can use form method=get. Can even use MVC. How can I achieve the ajax effect so page is not reloading on every paging/sorting? Should the parameters go into the url after # ?

Comment: Doing this with ajax is a completely different thing. It will not affect the address bar or bookmarking. I believe the simplest way to handle it is by wrapping your search option controls and result in an UpdatePanel. I suggest you turn the ajax part of this into a new question so an ajax expert can help you.